# cognos embedded - filters passed via API

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio, cognos-11

I wonder on whether it is possible with congnos embedded in watson studio to dynamically apply filters in the URL or via API.

I found this repository which contains JavaScript API reference documentation for IBM Cognos Analytics with classes and methods to work with dashboards, https://github.com/IBM/ca-dashboard-js-api.

May you advise on best way to proceed and point me to the most appropriate Javascript API I should focus on and use?

Thanks a lot in advance for shedding lights